# efficent way to drill down through xml feed multiple times

Tags: php, xml, function

Ive found myself drilling down through xml feeds quite allot, they are almost identical feeds apart from a couple of array names.

Ideally id want to make a sort of function that i can call, but i have no idea how to do it with this sort of data

```
//DRILLING DOWN TO THE PRICE ATTRIBUTE FOR EACH FEED & MAKING IT A WORKING VAR
  $wh_odds = $wh_xml->response->will->class->type->market->participant;
  $wh_odds_attrib = $wh_odds->attributes();
  $wh_odds_attrib['odds'];


  $lad_odds = $lad_xml->response->lad->class->type->market->participant;
  $lad_odds_attrib = $lad_odds->attributes();
  $lad_odds_attrib['odds'];
```

as you can see they are essentially the very similar, but im not quite sure how i can streamline the process of setting a working var without writing 3 lines each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're probably looking for is called [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement.xpath).

[XPath is a language](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?XpathLanguage) of it's own designed to pick stuff out of XML files. In your case, the xpath expression to get the `odds` attribute of all these elements is:

```
response/*/class/type/market/participant/@odds
```

You can also replace the `*` with the concrete element name *or* allow multiple names there and what not.

```
$odds = $lad_xml->xpath('response/*/class/type/market/participant/@odds');
```

Different to your code, this has all *attribute* elements inside the array (you have the attribute's parent element inside the variable). An example outcome (considering two of such elements) would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [odds] => a
                )

        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [odds] => a
                )

        )

)
```

You can turn that into strings as well easily:

```
$odds_strings = array_map('strval', $odds);

print_r($odds_strings);

Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => a
)
```

Xpath is especially useful if you say, you want to get all `participant` element's `odds` attributes:

```
//participant/@odds
```

You don't need to explicitly specify each of the parent element names.

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
 function getAttrib ($xmlObj, $attrName) {
      $wh_odds = $xmlObj->response->$attrName->class->type->market->participant;
      $wh_odds_attrib = $wh_odds->attributes();
      return $wh_odds_attrib['odds'];
}

getAttrib ($wh_xml, "will");
```

hope that helps.